# Как сделать разную шапку для планшета и десктопа на Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Есть сайт, который сделан на Elementor, нужно поправить адаптив  шапки для планшета и телефона. Я включил режим для планшета, и создал блоки заново, но он сохранился и для десктопа. Есть ли возможность изменения шапки на Elementor отдельно для десктопа и планшета?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При редактировании виджетов, вы можете скрывать/отображать определенные виджеты для десктопа, планшета и телефона. При редактировании виджета перейдите в Advanced -> Responsive
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, но теперь в адаптиве вместо скрытых элементов существует пробел. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Не совсем пойму о каком вы пробеле, можете подробнее описать или прикрепить скрин? Вообще вы можете скрывать не только виджеты, но и элементы, такие как колонки и секции.